# How to read multi line multi string registry entries in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to read the "-Dhttp.port" value with no luck.

AS you can see in the attached image, "Options" is a sub-key and I am able to read "Options" using the following snippet (this shows unnecessary PowerShell items too though)

```
Get-ItemProperty $PATH -Name "Options"
```

Now from the multi-line "Options" I want to read the value of specific sub-key "-Dhttp.port" which is 80 here

[image]

Output for Get-ItemProperty $PATH -Name "Options" is

[image]

I want to read only "Options", and from Options key I want to read value of "-Dhttp.port".

Comment: What have you got so far? Doesn't the Get-ItemProperty work properly?

Comment: It is working properly (as what the doc says), but I want only non Powershell items and also want to read a specific value of key inside that value from "Options". I was wondering if there is any easy way than writing code to avoid all PS items, then writing code to split based on space, then find out the value for "-Dhttp.port" I  have updated the original post with the output I get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PS>( Get-ItemProperty $PATH |select -ExpandProperty Options|where {$_ -match "-Dhttp.port"}).split("=")[1]
```

Comment: Thanks @Kayasax, was spot on !! ( I didn't knew about ExpandProperty)